# I want to use a filter regardless of whitespace in djangorestframework

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

i have

```py
class KceeService:

    def getTbBookCrwalingByTitleAndWriter(title, writer):
        bookData = []
        queryset = tb_book_crawling.objects.filter(title__icontains=title, 
        writer__icontains=writer).order_by('-publish_date')

        for query in queryset:
            bookData.append(TbBookCrawlingSerializer(query).data)
    
        return bookData
```

but title = 'new york 1' , real column data = 'new york1'

so, bookData is []

how to use title & column data overcome the whitespace?

I want your help.

thank,you

i removed the whitespace .

but , many title is same problems.

how to use filter() overcome the whitespace.